# Access violation when calling cublas function

Tags: cuda, cublas

I have a problem with the following code, when executing the call to cublasSrotg it throws an exception: "Access violation writing location 0x05200600", which is the address of the 'dA' pointer. When running the debugger it appears to be skipping the call to cudaMalloc, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
cublasHandle_t handle;
cublasCreate(&handle);
float hA[SIZE] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f };
int sizef = sizeof(float);
float* dA;
cudaMalloc((void**)&dA, SIZE * sizef);
cublasSetVector(SIZE, sizef, hA, 1, dA, 1);
float s, c;
cublasSrotg(handle, dA, dA + N, &c, &s);
cublasSrot(handle, N, dA, 1, dA + N, 1, &c, &s);
cublasGetVector(SIZE, sizef, dA, 1, hA, 1);
...
```

Comment: I would suggest adding cuda error checking.  You can find more information about cuda error checking on google.

This will help you see where your code went wrong and what the cuda error was.

Comment: cudaError error = cudaMalloc((void**)&dA, SIZE * sizef); See what it returns. If there's no error in cudaMalloc then check whether you're giving the right arguments to the function or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following line of code I gather that `SIZE` is equal to `4`.

```
float hA[SIZE] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f };
```

But then here, you do two strange things:

```
cublasSrotg(handle, dA, dA + N, &c, &s);
```

1. You mix host and device parameters to the same cublas function (I don't know if this is legal or not). `dA` is a device pointer and `s` and `c` are host variables.
2. You pass `dA` and `dA + N`.  Unless `N` is less than `4`, you will be indexing out of bounds, so that could be your problem.  Also, note that the first two inputs to cublasSrotg are in/out variables -- their initial value is used, but then overwritten.

Since they are overwritten, it's strange that you would then pass the same pointers to `cublasSrot`...

See the [CUBLAS Documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/CUDALibraries/doc/CUBLAS_Library.pdf) for full details.

**Edit:**

OP reveals that the problem was mixing device and host pointers, as well as not calling cudaMalloc to allocate the `c` and `s` values on the device.

Comment: I tried calling cublasSetPointerMode(handle, CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_DEVICE) before calling rotg (and passing only device pointers) and that fixed the access violation exception, but now it fails in cublasGetVector with CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR. To make it worse I checked with cudaGetLastError and it returns "unknown error"

Comment: The documentation for CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR says "An access to GPU memory space failed, which is usually caused by a failure to bind a texture. To correct: prior to the function call, unbind any previously bound textures." -- are you using textures at all?

Comment: Ok I've solved it. The problem was that I was not calling cudaMalloc properly for the 's' parameter in the first place :/  To sum up, the problems with the code I've posted were: mixing device and host parameters when calling rotg, and not setting the cublas pointer mode appropriately.